# Python: store the function's return value in a variable if called using thread

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'm using the threading library in order to perform some parallel data retrieval (then I need to concatenate the results obtained) however I'm not able to store the return of my function

Here's a simple example

```
def test(i):
    return i + 1

threading.Timer(0, x = test(0))
print(x) #Should Print 1
```

The problem that its forbidden to put x=test(0) while calling the thread

Is there a way to store the function's return value in a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading

def test(i):
    global x
    x = i + 1


x = 0
threading.Timer(0, test(0))
print(x)
```

Place a global variable outside of the function which can then be altered by the individual thread.

If you are however doing this to gather data, you will need to have a way of testing if the threads are complete before concatenating the results.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try the solution. Indeed Ill use the thread.Join to make sure that all threads are done gathering data.
Im using this method to gather data from a large db